Using openai langchain with Pinot DB for NLP to SQL
I'm trying to use ChatOpenAI from langchain_openai to create a Sql query chain. Instead of using the common mysql, I'm trying to implement Pinot DB queries. Is this possible with the extension of BaseTool and any custom wrapper around it?
